# How to set margin-top proeprly in WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am making the footer of my WP custom theme. I have footer div(inside which I place components). I also have a logo div(where my logo is). I need distance from 12px between the begening of the footer div till the logo div.

I am using this:

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footerlogo"> 
  <img id="pic" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/footer_logo.png">
    </div> .......


.footerlogo{ margin-top:30px;}
```

It doesnt show any differance. WHat is the proper way of doing that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hobnv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use padding on the footer div, for example:

```
.footer {
    padding-top: 12px;
}
```

This would add space between both the `.footer` and `.footerlogo` div elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/ss7Lp2nd/

Comment: It still does not change using padding.

Comment: I've added a fiddle to the original answer to demonstrate this better.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!